What does a correlation between predictions of training data and predictions of validation data tell me?
In my Machine Learning intro course I made several scatter plots of predictions for the california housing data set. Here is the most complete of them (created by a pipe using a sklearn StandardScaler in front of a sklearn KNearestNeighbor, both with default parameters):

The orange dots are predictions for the validation data and the blue dots are predictions for the training data.
I noticed a skew between the predictions of validation and training data, that is consistent between all of the plots, which to me suggests that (in pseudo math):
L(validation) ~ log(L(training)),
My interpretation of this assumption is that sklearn KNearestNeighbor with default parameters (5 neighbors, uniform weights) is not the best fit for predictions here.
Are this assumption and its interpretation correct, and if so, what can I do to make better predictions?

I believe that there is something fundamentally wrong: ideally, the points should all reside on the line -- which they don't. Since the deviations from the line are so severe the accuracy of the predictions mus be very poor (or you mislabeled the axes...). This would be my point of departure for some more digging into the problem if I were you.

Thank you, I will do that
